# Request generate two requests on api - error

Tags: angular, express, cors

I have an api in which I consume through an online store but I have a problem in the requests that the site makes. I always get two requests, one with OPTION and the other with POST, it happens that the api ends up being shuffled when I perform every time I make the first request or another one different. Can someone help me?

```
app.use(cors({ origin:true, credentials: true, preflightContinue: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before and it's an expected behavior related with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Then you will have two request on server side but just one callback response on front-end, so my recommendation is to validate the first **OPTION** request on server side and in the front-end you will get just one callback response.