# Angular Http Options and Delete sends two requests?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to send a request to the server to remove an object based on id. I'm using Web Api as back end.

**Angular**

```
removable: string = 'http://localhost:49579/api/resource/remove/28';

     this._http.options(removable,{headers}).subscribe((value)=>console.log("success"),(error)=>console.log(error));
```

**WebApi**

```
    [HttpOptions]
    [Route("api/resource/remove/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromUri] int id)
    {

        if (MovieRepository.Remove(id))
        {
            return Ok("Movie was removed");
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Movie was not removed");
        }
    }
}
```

I get back two requests, one is OK and the other one is Bad Request. I also tried it with Http DELETE but it produces the same effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to an actual DELETE request:

```
this._http.delete(removable,{headers}).subscribe((value)=>console.log("success"),(error)=>console.log(error));
```

Not sure why you would manually call an `options` request, Angular already does this for every request you make.

Comment: Then it sends options request and delete request. Options is OK and delete returns 405 method not allowed

Comment: Then you must change something in the backend side of things. I haven't worked with WebApi so I'm not sure how to do it, I just know sending two options requests sounds really wrong when what you're actually trying to do is 1 options and 1 delete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and it's an expected behavior related with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Then you will have two request on server side but just one callback response on front-end, so my recommendation is to validate the first **OPTION** request on server side and in the front-end you will get just one callback response

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053096/6651984)